# How to change the current password optional

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

How do I change the current optional password in edit account section in Magento 2 as customer is already logged in, hence I don't want customer to put the current password again for the store.
How can I achieve this for my store?

Comment: what do you want to change?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this my following steps:

**Step 1:**
Copy the below file to your theme:

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/edit.phtml

And remove required class from below section:

```
<div class="field password current">
    <label class="label" for="current-password"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Current Password')) ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="current_password" id="current-password" data-input="current-password" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Step 2:**
Copy the below file to your theme:

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/change-email-password.js

and change the method **_showAll**:

```
_showAll: function () {
    $(this.options.titleSelector).html(this.options.titleChangeEmailAndPassword);

    $(this.options.mainContainerSelector).show();
    $(this.options.emailContainerSelector).show();
    $(this.options.newPasswordContainerSelector).show();
    $(this.options.confirmPasswordContainerSelector).show();

    //$(this.options.currentPasswordSelector).attr('data-validate', '{required:true}').prop('disabled', false); // Comment this line
    $(this.options.currentPasswordSelector).prop('disabled', false); // Added this line
    $(this.options.emailSelector).attr('data-validate', '{required:true}').prop('disabled', false);
    this._updatePasswordFieldWithEmailValue();
    $(this.options.confirmPasswordSelector).attr(
        'data-validate',
        '{required:true, equalTo:"' + this.options.newPasswordSelector + '"}'
    ).prop('disabled', false);
},
```

**Step 3:**
Override the following class

> vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php

and change the function **changePasswordForCustomer**(Its private method if override not working then try to edit the vendor class)

```
private function changePasswordForCustomer($customer, $currentPassword, $newPassword)
{
    try {
        //$this->getAuthentication()->authenticate($customer->getId(), $currentPassword); // Comment this line
    } catch (InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $e) {
        throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('The password doesn\'t match this account.'));
    }
    $customerEmail = $customer->getEmail();
    $this->credentialsValidator->checkPasswordDifferentFromEmail($customerEmail, $newPassword);
    $customerSecure = $this->customerRegistry->retrieveSecureData($customer->getId());
    $customerSecure->setRpToken(null);
    $customerSecure->setRpTokenCreatedAt(null);
    $this->checkPasswordStrength($newPassword);
    $customerSecure->setPasswordHash($this->createPasswordHash($newPassword));
    $this->destroyCustomerSessions($customer->getId());
    $this->customerRepository->save($customer);

    return true;
}
```

Vendor edit is not good practice.

Comment: How to handle current password in AccountManagement model file......

Comment: Did you try to change the function I have mentioned? This function ignores the current password validation and checking.

Comment: Yes. i have done it. But i need to override  account management in my module file ....How to solve this...I spend lot of time for this..

Comment: Without override everything works fine as you want?

Comment: Yes.....its working fine

Comment: OK.............

Comment: Its a api model file ....can you override this model file ?

Comment: I don't think private function can be overriden. Need to find different way. You can close this question as answer already working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80140/discussion-between-mano-m-and-sukumar-gorai).